# Get socket file descriptor in kprobe BPF

Tags: sockets, file-descriptor, bpf, ebpf

I am tracing some socket-related kernel functions. I wonder how I can get the file descriptor of the current socket in the BPF program.

Comment: What kernel functions? What does your current BPF program look like? What did you already try?

Comment: For example, I want to trace tcp_new_evetn_data_sent (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.1/source/net/ipv4/tcp_output.c#L72), and want to write some data into a map that is indexed by the socket file descriptor. How can I get the file descriptor for the current socket?

Comment: I'm guessing you have some userspace process that creates/opens that socket. Why don't you trace that syscall (or one of the kernel functions called by that syscall) to get the fd <-> socket mapping?

Comment: Hello. So you mean in the system call I establish a map from the sock to descriptor, then in the function say tcp_new_event_data_sent, I use it to get the file descriptor. Is that right?  But how to do that in, say, __sys_socket (https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.11-rc7/source/net/socket.c#L1479), which corresponds to the socket system call.  Both socket and descriptor are not accessible in the kretprobe, right? Sorry not very familiar with bpf.

Comment: You can save the syscall arguments in a map at kprobe, retrieve them at kretprobe to associate with the returned fd.

Comment: __sys_socket returns a pointer to a file struct. Do you know how to convert that to a file descriptor?

Comment: `__sys_socket` should return a file descriptor, as per the socket(2) man page.